# opengl calculate normal for face

Tags: c++, opengl

I am attempting to load models exported from Blender into OpenGL. Particularly, I followed the source code from this [tutorial](https://tutorialsplay.com/opengl/2014/09/17/lesson-9-loading-wavefront-obj-3d-models/) to help me get started. Because the loader is fairly simple, it only read in the vertex coordinates as well as face indices, ignoring the normal and tex.

It then calculates the normal for each face:

```
        float coord1[3] = { Faces_Triangles[triangle_index], Faces_Triangles[triangle_index+1],Faces_Triangles[triangle_index+2]};
        float coord2[3] = {Faces_Triangles[triangle_index+3],Faces_Triangles[triangle_index+4],Faces_Triangles[triangle_index+5]};
    float coord3[3] = {Faces_Triangles[triangle_index+6],Faces_Triangles[triangle_index+7],Faces_Triangles[triangle_index+8]};
float *norm = this->calculateNormal( coord1, coord2, coord3 );


        float* Model_OBJ::calculateNormal( float *coord1, float *coord2, float *coord3 )
        {
           /* calculate Vector1 and Vector2 */
           float va[3], vb[3], vr[3], val;
           va[0] = coord1[0] - coord2[0];
           va[1] = coord1[1] - coord2[1];
           va[2] = coord1[2] - coord2[2];

           vb[0] = coord1[0] - coord3[0];
           vb[1] = coord1[1] - coord3[1];
           vb[2] = coord1[2] - coord3[2];

           /* cross product */
           vr[0] = va[1] * vb[2] - vb[1] * va[2];
           vr[1] = vb[0] * va[2] - va[0] * vb[2];
           vr[2] = va[0] * vb[1] - vb[0] * va[1];

           /* normalization factor */
           val = sqrt( vr[0]*vr[0] + vr[1]*vr[1] + vr[2]*vr[2] );

            float norm[3];
            norm[0] = vr[0]/val;
            norm[1] = vr[1]/val;
            norm[2] = vr[2]/val;


            return norm;
        }
```

I have 2 questions.

1. How do I know if the normal is facing inwards or outwards? Is there some ordering of the vertices in each row in the .obj file that gives indication how to calculate the normal?
2. In the initialization function, he uses `GL_SMOOTH`. Is this incorrect, since I need to provide normals for each vertex if using `GL_SMOOTH` instead of `GL_FLAT`?

Comment: If your file contains normals, you shouldn't ignore them. What you're calculating are only face normals, not the actual surface normals. Unless you really want flat shading only.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. However, I've just got started with the tutorial example, so I didn't really know how to load in the vertex normal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Question 1

[`glFrontFace`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glFrontFace.xml) determines wind order

Wind order means, what order a set of vertexes should appear for a normal to be considered positive.  Consider the triangle below.  It's vertexes are defined clockwise.  If we told OpenGL `glFrontFace(GL_CW)` (That clockwise means front face) then the normal would essentially be sticking right out of the screen towards you in order to be considered "outward".

On a side note, **counter-clockwise** is the default and what you should stick with.

No matter what, you need should really define normals especially if you want to do any lighting in your scene as they are used for lighting calculation.  `glFrontFace` just lets you tell OpenGL which way you want to interpret what the front of a polygon is.

In the above example, and below diagram, if we told OpenGL that we define faces **counter-clockwise** and also `glEnable`d `glCullFace` and set it to `GL_BACK` then our triangle wouldn't show up because we would be looking at the back of it and we told OpenGL not to show the back of polygons.

You can read more about face culling here: [Face Culling](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Face_Culling).

[image: Triangle with a clockwise wind]

Wavefront `.obj` [has support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file#Vertex_Normal_Indices) for declaring normals in a file if you don't want to create them yourself.  Just make sure your exporter adds them.

Additionaly, Wavefront wants each vertex to have a normal defined:

```
f v1//vn1 v2//vn2 v3//vn3 ...
```

Where `vN` is the vertex of the `f` face and `vnN` is the normal of the vertex.  By providing a normal for each vertex, you achieve a smoother looking surface than you would by defining a normal per face or by setting all of the normals of vertexes of the same face to be the same.  Take a look at this question to see the difference you can make on a sphere: [OpenGL: why do I have to set a normal with glNormal?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/50656/18988)

If your .obj file doesn't have normals defined, I would use the face definition order and cross two edges of the defined face.  Consider the method used here: [Calculating a Surface Normal](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Calculating_a_Surface_Normal)

**Edit**

I think I may be a little confusing.  The front face of a polygon is only slightly related to its normals.  Normals are only really used for lighting calculations.  You don't *have* to have them, but they are one of the big variables used in calculating how lit your object is.

I am explaining the "front-faced-ness" of a polygon at the same time because it sort of makes sense, when talking about convex polygons, that your normal would stick out of the "front" of your triangle with respect to the shape you are making.

If you created a huge cave, or if your camera were to mostly reside inside of some concave shape, then it would make sense to have your normals point inwards since your light sources are probably going to want to bounce off of the inside of your shape.

## Question 2

`GL_SMOOTH` determines which of the shading models you want to use with `glShadeModel`

`GL_SMOOTH` means smooth shading, where color is actually interpolated between each vertex, vs `GL_FLAT` means flat shading, where only one one color will be used.  Typically, you'll use the default value, `GL_SMOOTH`.

You don't *have* to define normals for each vertex in either case.  However, if you want `GL_SMOOTH` to look "good" you'll probably want to as it will interpolate as it renders between each vertex rather than just picking one vertex for properties.

---

Also, bear in mind that all of this goes out the window whenever you leave the fixed-function pipeline and start using shaders.

Comment: Let me know if I understand the following correctly. 1. if I use glFrontFace in the code, I don't have to explicitly calculate the normal for each face. OpenGL performs the calculation for me. 2.  For GL_SMOOTH, I do have to have different normals for each vertex, otherwise it's actually similar to GL_FLAT.

Comment: @goh I added a few more details to hopefully answer your follow up questions.  You don't have to specify a front face.  However, if you *know* that you're putting all your vertexes into the pipeline but nothing is showing up, it might be that you're looking at the back of your shape as defined by the front-face.  You need normals if you want OpenGL to do any lighting calculations for your though.

Comment: Ok, so glFrontFace is used essentially for face culling which is mainly to hide/show polygon determined by the orientation of its face to the camera, whereas the normal we are discussing is mainly towards lighting purposes. however, is it true that if a light is shining in the same direction a shape is facing, then it has the same effects of not being shown?

Comment: @goh Almost.  In fixed function pipeline, there would probably still be ambient light that would appear on the shape surface since normals are not usually included in the calculation of ambient light.

Comment: So in a obj file, I can always presume that the vertex order for the faces (assuming the normals are not provided) are in a CCW direction, and the face normals can be calculated accordingly?